# Change menuitems visibility based on a shared preference value inside onCreateOptionsMenu

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, navigation-drawer

I need to remove some values from my Navigation drawer based on role get from login. I tried two methods. One is change menu based on role value and second is setVisibilty based on role value. But issue is that i cant get shared preference value inside onCreateOptionsMenu. When it is given in onCreate the value getting fine. Dont know why it is happening. I totally stucked in this issue.

**Method 1**

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    SharedPreferences prefs1 = getSharedPreferences("eduplus", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    String role = prefs1.getString("roleId", null);
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),role,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    assert role != null;
    if(role.equals("parent"))
    {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.drawer, menu);
    }
    else
    {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.drawer1,menu);
    }
    return true;
}
```

**Method 2**

```
@Override
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
    SharedPreferences prefs1 = getSharedPreferences("eduplus", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    String role = prefs1.getString("roleId", null);
    Log.d("rolevalueval",role);
    if (role.equals("student")) {
        menu.findItem(R.id.leaverequest).setVisible(false);
    }
    return true;
}
```

Both methods do not work because shared preference value is not getting

Comment: where do you save the roleId key in your prefs?

Comment: @Arjun , replace getsharedpref with `getSharedPreferences("eduplus", 0)` in `onPrepareOptionsMenu ` and check you are getting string **role**.

Comment: Are you getting `NullPointerException` in `onCreateOptionsMenu()` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're trying to inflate drawer menu inside NavigationView. To inflate it use below code in acitivity `onCreate()`.

```
NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
navigationView.getMenu().clear();
if(role.equals("parent")){
    navigationView.inflateMenu(R.menu.drawer);
}
else
{
    navigationView.inflateMenu(R.menu.drawer1);
}
```